Recognizing sections of a screen made by the grid lines
I am trying to count the numer of objects in jpg files using opencv.
Each picture has 5 horizontal lines and 5 vertical lines producing subsections in a screen.
I need to count the objects per each subsection.
The grid lines are somewhat irregular and slanted in each pictures.
What is the best to approach?
